# Fill a list in a do loop returns the list empty

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning Racket and I don't know why lst is always empty:

```
#lang racket

(define sort-asc-by-second
  (lambda (lst)
    (sort lst
          (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y))))))

(define sum
  (lambda (lst)
    (apply + (map cdr lst))
  )
)

(define greater-than
    (lambda (lst y)
      (cond ((null? lst) (void))
            ((>= (cdr (car lst)) y) (car lst))
            (else (greater-than (cdr lst) y)))))

(define my-procedure
  (lambda (lst)
    (define sorted (sort-asc-by-second lst))
    (define suma (sum lst))
    (define probabilidades (map (lambda (p) (cons (car p) (/ (cdr p) suma))) sorted))

    (define prob (random))

    (car (greater-than lst prob))
   )
)
(define lst '())

(do ([x 6000 (- x 1)]
     (set! lst (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))))
  ((zero? x) lst))

(display lst)
```

I want to modify the lst list inside the do, but it doesn't.

Do you know why lst is empty?

**UPDATE**
I have tested the following instructions with the following results:

```
> (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))
'a

> (set! lst (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3))))
> (display lst)
'a
```

I still doesn't know why `lst` is empty when I do the loop.

Comment: haven't you received some error messages?

Comment: No. I haven't got any error.

Comment: did `(set! (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3))) lst)` work as you expected, when you tried evaluating it at the REPL prompt? What did `(my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))` return, when you tried it at the REPL prompt?

Comment: @WillNess REPL prompt?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=REPL+prompt+Racket) [says](https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/repl.html).

Comment: @WillNess I have updated the question.

Comment: Please don't keep adding new questions to the end of an old one. Instead, think about how the old value of `lst` could possibly occur in the result of `(my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))`.

Comment: @VansFannel I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I make it work:

```
(do ([x 6000 (- x 1)])
  ((zero? x))
  (set! lst (cons (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3))) lst)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `do`-form is

```
(do (initialisers)
    (stop-condition end-expression)
    body)
```

but you have written

```
(do (initialiser body)
    (stop-condition end-expression))
```

with the unfortunate effect that the value of `(my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))` has been bound to the name `set!` inside the loop, and `lst` is never modified.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you mean this `lst`:

```
(define lst '())
```

You defined it as the empty list.  You never set it to anything else.

Maybe the [documentation of `set!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/set_.html) helps a bit.  While you are there, look for the documentation of `do`.

The next problem you might encounter is that setting something to the same value repeatedly will not result in an observable effect (except CPU temperature maybe).

Comment: But I modify it inside the do loop.

Comment: No, you don't.  Take a look at the `set!` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
(do ([x 6000 (- x 1)]
     (set! lst (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))))
  ((zero? x) lst))
```

is the same as

```
(do (  [x    6000  (- x 1)                                ]
       [set! lst   (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))]  )
  ((zero? x) lst))
```

You define `set!` as one of your loop variables (the other is `x`). `lst` is its initial value, and `(my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))` its step expression.

So *your* local binding for `set!` is repeatedly set to `'a` while `x` is counting down to `0`; then the same `lst` -- which were never changed -- is returned.

Try it:

```
> (do ([x 0 (- x 1)]
       (set! 1 (my-procedure '((a . 1)(b . 2)(c . 3)))))
  ((zero? x) set!))
1
```